# Not able to retrieve data in a particular columns with Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to load a huge text file of size 2GB and trying to extract data in a particular column using pandas

```
LOCATION_ID                    PRODUCT_ID  PRODUCT_DESC                   NET_SALES                         SALES_DATE
------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------ --------------------------------- ----------
100020                                   8 Lotto Texas                                                8.000 01/01/2009
100020                                   9 Pick 3                                                   105.500 01/01/2009
100020                                  10 Cash Five                                                  7.000 01/01/2009
100020                                  12 Texas Two Step
```

The data looks like this what I am trying to do is extract number of unique columns in Location ID

I tried using pandas.read_csv(file,chunksize=4) but I am not getting anything in columns only indexes are present. I am kind of stuck, I was able to do it using simple file read but since the size of file is so huge python compiler crashes.  How can I achieve the desired result using Pandas ? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That file doesn't look like a csv, given that there don't seem to be any commas, and it doesn't even seem to be a delimited file.  You might have better luck treating it as a fixed-width-format file and using [`read_fwf`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_fwf.html):

```
>>> pd.read_fwf("296.dat", skiprows=[1])
   LOCATION_ID  PRODUCT_ID    PRODUCT_DESC  NET_SALES  SALES_DATE
0       100020           8     Lotto Texas        8.0  01/01/2009
1       100020           9          Pick 3      105.5  01/01/2009
2       100020          10       Cash Five        7.0  01/01/2009
3       100020          12  Texas Two Step        NaN         NaN
```

You can do the same `chunksize` tricks with `fwf` as you can with `read_csv`, so you can limit the amount in memory at any one time.

Also note that here I simply used the "infer column width" default; you may have to specify them manually, depending on your data.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will try that but how can I access the column1 of the file i.e Location Id, or converting it to any data frame will that help ? It gives memory error my ram is 4GB I tried using chunk I still cannot access the data based on columns

Comment: The above *is* a DataFrame, as are the chunks you'd get if you used `chunked = pd.read_fwf("yourfilename.txt", skiprows=[1], chunksize=1000)` and then iterated over it.  You can get unique values using `df["LOCATION_ID"].unique()`, and then collect those.

Comment: On doing that I get an error stating keyerror= LOCATION_ID

Comment: I was able to do it, as I was skipping rows it was not getting columns I added name to the columns now it is working fine. Thank you so much!!